# How to split an ES6 class definition across files cross-referencing private members?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class, private-members

Referencing a private member E.G. `this.#rts()` gives the error:

> SyntaxError: Private field '*#rts*' must be declared in an enclosing class

Although when that line is evaluated, the function has been assigned to an instance method and *this* is correctly bound.
Is there a way to achieve this, I.E. **to reference private members across files**?

*Note:* I'm using Node 13.

Example:

```
import {Cpu6502} from "./cpu6502.mjs";
console.log((new Cpu6502).beq());
```

*cpu6502.mjs*:

```
import {beq} from "./instructions.mjs";
export class Cpu6502 {
    beq = beq // `this` is correctly bound
    #rts = () => "RTS"
}
```

*instructions.mjs*:

```
export function beq() {
    return this.#rts() // If this line references a public member instead,  
                       // it works fine and `this` is correctly bound.
}
```

Comment: Please post your code *here*.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] HERE at SO of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Any help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58962695/how-to-define-private-methods-in-a-js-class ?

Comment: @mplungjan No, it doesn't address referencing the private member across files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach but probably you want somenthing like a mixin

```
import { lda } from './instructions.mjs'

export class Cpu6502 {
    constructor() {
       this.lda = lda.bind(this);
    }
    A = 0xFF
    #rts() {
        return "RTS";
    }
    ldx() {
        return this.lda();
    }
}`
```

Comment: I get this error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:81:18)`

Comment: What are you're using to transpile/bundle it?maybe you can try to move the A = 0xFF in the constructor.

Comment: I'm just running it with Node 13. And already removed A because it was a leftover of an old test _(still the same cryptic error)_, I just need to call a private method from a bound function declared in another file.

Comment: Reading the code I can tell you is a little bit tricky what you're trying to do. https://codesandbox.io/s/async-breeze-wpjty?file=/src/index.js but this should be want you want.

Comment: Yeah I figured out the most common solution would be the underscore convention.